# Excluding a file while using Copy-Item

Tags: powershell

I'm having a few issues while copying desktop files as a part of the back up process from local folder to server.

My script automatically creates a backup folder on the server and I just realised when it creates the back up folder windows automatically creates a `desktop.ini` file, and as `desktop.ini` is a system file the script failed to write another `desktop.ini` from desktop to the backup folder in server.

My initial code was :

```
Copy-Item ("$Global:localBackupRestoreLocation\Desktop\$file") ("$Global:remoteBackupRestorePath\$nameOfbackupDirectory") ($recursive="true")
```

But I was to use the exclude in that line and I know exclude does not work recursively and I have to use `Get-ChildItem`.

Comment: [`robocopy`](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc733145.aspx) might be a better approach to what you're trying to do here.

Comment: hey mate tried using robocopy but its not copying files under subfoldrs.

Comment: Please take a closer look at the command options. I'm not going to read the documentation to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

$Exclude = @('desktop.ini')

copy-item -Path $Source -Destination $Dest -Exclude $Exclude